# Messy Selected effect in continuous form datasheet (Microsoft Access 2010)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

Is there a way to clean up the way a selected item appears in a datasheet that is in 'continuous' mode?  [image: Selected item in a coninuous datasheet.]

The item is "202" but as you can see, it just looks messy.  Tried looking for properties that I could access during the click event, but nothing is obvious.

Comment: Is your definition of 'messy' "difficult to read; not crisp and clear" or something else? You have control over the background color, font color, name and size, bold, etc.  Unfortunately, since you are using a continuous form, if you try to change the control in the click event, that control on all rows will change. IMO, there is a point during application development when functionality trumps 'pretty'. Or look at: http://access.mvps.org/access/forms/frm0047.htm

Comment: Yes. I agree. I originally had it in data sheet mode. But it is used in a working group meeting so I thought I'd try. Thanks for the other tip. I'll give it a whirl.